# Variable does not exists?

Tags: apex, trigger, account, developer-console, console

I cannot compare the value of two different list field(ie name)

Getting me error

Variable does not exist: Name

```
List<Account> actLst = new List<Account>();
Set<String> userNames = new Set<String>();

List<Account> accList = [SELECT Id,Name,duplicate__c FROM Account where 
            Id Not In (Select AccountId from Contact) And 
            Id Not In (Select AccountId from Opportunity)];

List<Account> accCont = [SELECT Id,Name,duplicate__c FROM Account where 
            Id In (Select AccountId from Contact)];

List<Account> accOpp = [SELECT Id,Name,duplicate__c FROM Account where 
            Id In (Select AccountId from Opportunity)];

for(Account account_i : accList)
{

  if( (accCont.Name != account_i.Name) ||  (account_i.Name != accOpp.Name)  ) 
   {    

     if(!userNames.contains(account_i.Name)) 
      {
        userNames.add(account_i.Name);
      }
     else
      {
        account_i.duplicate__c = true;
    actLst.add(account_i);
      } 
   }
 else {
        account_i.duplicate__c = true;
        actLst.add(account_i);
      }
    system.debug('actLst >> ' + actLst);
    update actLst;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your this piece of code is causing the error:-

```
if( (accCont.Name != account_i.Name) ||  (account_i.Name != accOpp.Name)  )
```

You are trying to access the value from list directly using **accCont.Name or accOpp.Name** but you cannot as Name exist on single instance of Account but List is group of accounts.

To access the value from a list, Use Get method like this:-

```
List<Integer> myList = new List<Integer>();
myList.add(47);
Integer myNumber = myList.get(0);
system.assertEquals(47, myNumber);

List<String> colors = new String[3];
colors[0] = 'Red';
colors[1] = 'Blue';
colors[2] = 'Green';
```

Read more here:- [List Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_list.htm)

In your case, You can use Map instead of list like this:-

```
Map<Id,Account> accMap = new Map<Id,Account>([SELECT Id,Name,duplicate__c FROM Account where 
            Id In (Select AccountId from Contact) And 
            Id In (Select AccountId from Opportunity)]);
```

and get the account name using id as key.

Comment: Thanks sanket your solution is very helpful.

Comment: You can accept this as answer.